# Using java Asm lib to delete the filed of a Class

Tags: java, json

i meet a problem. the org.Json lib's JSONObject do not have a equals method. but it have a toString method. I want to "abc".equals(JsonObject.toStirng()). here is the problem.

toStirng() string is not sorted. for exmple `{"aa":"11","bb":"22"}`, maybe, toStirng is this :

`{"bb":"22","aa":"11"}`, the String not equals, but json object actually equals. I decomplie the

org.json.JSONObject:

```
private Map map; 

public JSONObject()
   {
      map = new HashMap();
   }
```

i do not have the source code, i want to use asm.lib to modify the class.

so, i want to change one places , one is :

```
 public JSONObject()
    {
       map = new HashMap(); -->map = new LinkedHashMap();
    }
```

so, the string generated from toString() will be sorted, that is what i wanted.

I do  know how to add a field, but i do not know how to **Modify and delete** a filed or a

method.

Brothers or Sisters is your time, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The json.org Java source is available there: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java. It is opensource but no license is specified.

You can then modify the source code.

Comment: i just want to use asm to modify the class, baby, this is another question. :-)